# javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved

Tags: java, swing

I'm a beginner at Java programming. I encountered an error - 
`javax.swing.JComponent cannot be resolved` whenever I execute the following program.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
class apples
{
public static void main(String args[])
{

String a = JOptionPane .showInputDialog("Enter a number");
String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter another number");

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b);

    int sum = num1 + num2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sum is "+sum, Answer,JOptionPane.PLANE_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Comment: `JOptionPane.PLANE_MESSAGE` must be `JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE`

Comment: Did you forget importing `JComponent`?

Comment: Where do you use `JComponent` in your code? Where do you get the error (which line)?

Comment: I really get this error in the line :

    String a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a number");

Comment: I thought it is enough to import the JOptionPane. I did not import anything else. Can you say tell what I have missed?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String a = JOptionPane .showInputDialog("Enter a number");
String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter another number");

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(a);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(b);

    int sum = num1 + num2;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sum is "+sum, "Answer",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

You were using incorrect JOptionPane. You need to use PLAIN_MESSAGE instead of PLANE_MESSAGE. Also the Answer field which is the title needs to be a string
I suggest using an IDE like eclipse or netbeans so that you can avoid such issues.

Comment: Can you explian your answer?

Comment: You were using incorrect JOptionPane. You need to use PLAIN_MESSAGE instead of PLANE_MESSAGE. Also the Answer field which is the tiltle needs to be a string